# Difference between "shameless" and "unashamed"

Tags: meaning, difference

Could anyone please tell me what's the difference in meaning between the words 'shameless' and 'unashamed'?

Comment: '[Shameless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shameless?show=0&t=1409029584)' and '[Unashamed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unashamed)' - they both are synonyms at least for MW.

Answer (score 4):

*unashamed* is the negative of [ashamed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/ashamed) meaning not feeling shame, embarassment, etc.

[shameless](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/shameless) means not having any sense of shame, modesty, etc.

So you could be *ashamed* or (the opposite) *unashamed*, but if you are *shameless* you do not care about embarrassment, shame, modesty etc.

Comment: "unashamed" has the connotation of being related to a particular event or action that might cause a person to be ashamed.  "shameless" can refer to a person's attitude about everything, or be limited to a person's attitude toward a particular kind of activity.  For example, "shameless self-promotion" is a valid phrase; it means that the person does not have any sense of shame about self-promoting activities, but does not say anything about whether they have a sense of shame about other activities.

Comment: thank you both for answering. Jasper, your explanation was pretty helpful and made it clear to me :)

Comment: I've just asked my English teacher about this, and she added that a person can be 'shameless' only because of their own attitude and behavior, whereas a person who feels '(un)ashamed' doesn't necessarily have to be the agent but could also feel like that because of other people's actions.

Comment: Actually, being 'shameless' is connected with others in a wider sense, since it's the society that decides what sort of behavior contributes to identifying shamelessness, but that's not the point :)